# Predefine the text and replace that predefined text while writing the mail in outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

As part of my work I need to ask customers to provide some set of logs from specific location from the client computer. I have 4 different set of logs , depending on the issue I ask for a one specific set out of 4 logs.

The issue is everytime I have to write those log fine names. Is there way if I type in my mail saying SET1_LOGS so it will be replaced by actual set of log file name of the set1 logs in the Microsoft outlook

something like below

## define SET1_LOGS = abc.txt, def.txt, abc123.txt

## define SET2_LOGS = ghi.txt, jkl.txt, abc123.txt

In my mail if I type SET1_LOGS then it should be replaced with abc.txt, def.txt, abc123.txt

Comment: You can improve this question by adding more details and making it useful to others. https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try using a text expander like [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) or [TextExpander](https://textexpander.com/).
For AutoHotkey, the syntax would be

```
::SET1_LOGS::abc.txt, def.txt, abc123.txt
```

Comment: Is it not possible from outlook itself without installing the extra tools?

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2019/04/03/outlook-quick-parts-autotext/

> Outlook Quick Parts is a gallery of reusable pieces of content that
>   you can quickly insert into your email messages as well as
>   appointments, meeting requests, contacts, and tasks. Microsoft defines
>   this feature as "building blocks".
>
> **Auto-complete Quick Parts with the Enter key** In Outlook 2016 and Outlook 2019, Quick Parts can also be auto-completed by hitting the
>   Enter key.
>
> You just start typing the name and as soon as it becomes unique the
>   "Press ENTER to Insert" suggestion appears. Press the Enter key and
>   the content is inserted straight away.

Comment: found by Googling "outlook autocomplete text"

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, I'm afraid there is not a build-in method for this in Outlook client. You may try using any tools or asking this question in Outlook for developers forum.